# Why can't I Import Image?

Tags: reactjs, image

Can you please tell me why I can not keep image and data files in public folder in react js app,It is showing error. Also if I keep Image in the src folder, I can not use image tag and write the path in the src attribute because if I write in this way, browser doesnt show it

But if I import image path in a variable and write the variable in the src attribute as string then  I can see the image . But that's not what I want because I need multiple images to import at once by map.

Comment: Could you mention the error that occurred when keeping the images in public folder?

Comment: thanks for replying , it is telling me that ,  I can not keep data like this in public folder.

Comment: Please show your code. I believe you can use a relative path in the img tag.

Comment: Hello, I have solved the problem . If I import like this : const imagePath = require(`../Images/${props.img}`);  then it works . But I am showing the code in the next comment

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/96421ce1 here is the code where I was trying to import images